# Does ArcGIS Directions API take Traffic into consideration when calculating Driving Time?

Tags: routing, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to calculate the Estimated Time of Arrival (ETA) between 2 locations and I need to take traffic into consideration.

I found this API call but it isn't clear if it includes traffic in the time estimates.

For example, the [RouteService](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r300000036000000) response below has "totalDriveTime"

```
"directions": [
        {
            "routeId": <routeId>,
            "routeName": "<routeName>",
            "summary": {
                "totalLength": <totalLength>,
                "totalTime": <totalTime>,
                "totalDriveTime": <totalDriveTime>,
                "envelope": {
                    <envelope>
                }
            },
```

Comment: based on the lack of mention of traffic at https://developers.arcgis.com/en/features/directions/ I'd guess that it doesn't